# Multiply two df in GPU (cudf)

Tags: python, dataframe, cudf

I have two dataframe in GPU. I want to multiply each element of each df.
Here is a simple version of my dataframes:

```
import cudf
a = cudf.DataFrame()
a['c1'] = [1, 2]
b = cudf.DataFrame()
b['c1'] = [2, 5]
```

I want to see this output:

```
    c1
0   2
1   10
```

I am using `a.multiply(b)`, however, I get error;`AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute multiply`

Can you please help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of cuDF, this works as expected. You may be using an older version in which this API was not yet implemented. I recommend upgrading.

```py
import cudf

a = cudf.DataFrame()
a['c1'] = [1, 2]
b = cudf.DataFrame()
b['c1'] = [2, 5]

print(a.multiply(b))
   c1
0   2
1  10
```